# The closing dialog push down the blocks shown in the flag page

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, flag-queue, close-dialog

I voted to close a question on meta from the flag page, and the page appeared as in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comparing the previous screenshot with the following one, it is evident that the chat blocks shown to the right have been pushed down.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The bug is that stuff in the background you can barely see anyway is temporarily mispositioned while a dialog that has your complete focus is open in the foreground?

Comment: The bug is that the dialog box should not push down other elements in the page. When I vote to close a question from the question page, the dialog box doesn't push down elements in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed, as it doesn't happen anymore.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The blocks shown on the right side are still in the same order, once the dialog box is displayed.